# How do I create a Shortcut Link on my Favorites Sidebar with batch?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I would really like to know if it is possible to create a shortcut link in my favorites sidebar on Windows 7 with batch code. When I want a shortcut to a specific folder, I will drag the folder up to the "Favorites" star on my Windows 7 sidebar, and it will create a link to the folder. I use the below batch code and it moves files into my favorites folder but does not create a link in the favorites sidebar. I want a link to just the directory. Does anyone know if it is possible to do this? Below is the code I'm using.

```
@echo off

%systemroot%\System32\xcopy /y "N:\Call Center\Southwest Power Pads\Blank Folder" "C:\Users\user1\Links"

pause
```

Comment: In what directory this sidebar stores shortcuts, or gets shortcuts from? Right click on any shortcut and click _Open file location_, if any.

Comment: You are talking about `.lnk` files? you cannot create such with pure batch scripting, but you could lend sode from other languages native to Windows like PowerShell, VBScript or JavaScript...

Comment: I'd be okay with learning how to do it with PowerShell. Do you have the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question:
[How to make a shortcut from CMD?](https://superuser.com/questions/392061/how-to-make-a-shortcut-from-cmd)
 -

I found an alternative, but with similar function and easier implementation.

Creates a symbolic link.

```
MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

        /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
                symbolic link.
        /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
        /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
        Link    Specifies the new symbolic link name.
        Target  Specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
                refers to.
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out and see if it works. But what pathway do I use to get it in the Favorites Sidebar and not the favorites folder?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would work but unfortunately I don't have "sufficient privileges" to perform this actions. So stupid. I'll try it when I gain temporary admin rights.

Comment: This is the best path I found: %USERPROFILE%\Links
You can open the cmd with admin rights by right click and choose "Run as Administrator".